# retrieve database values based on dates using ajax codeigniter php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I want to retrieve database values using ajax based on date range selected on the form by using codeigniter. The scenario is very straight forward. when the user select the daterange from the datepicker the desired system should callback to DB for retrieveing specific student's report and fill the bootstrap table with retrieved values to new  without reloading the page for getting data.

**view page of attendance checkout:-**
[image]

**attendance table on database:-**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Php query,

```
select *
from table_name
where date(date) between date('from date') and date('to date')
```

Ajax for this

```
$("#generate").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path to controller method',
        type: 'post',
        data: {fromdate:$("#fromdate").val(),todate:$("#todate").val()},
        success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

For generate button give id as generate, also give from from date and to date

echo the content in controller, it will come in ajax success in `data`. you can append to required div.

Comment: hello Nirajan .. i have implemented your suggestion but it seems not worked at all.. i have posted the whole code how i implement .. so please suggest me the right way please

Comment: @SumanDahal which part is not working?? what is alert giving??

Comment: alert doesn't gives any result at all. button is clicked but it doesn't show any alert

Comment: i have tested the alert by modifying my controller by just echo 'name'; and it shows the alert but retrieving from DB is not working ...

Comment: I think the ajax doesn't send the values to controller.. because i have also tested it with echoing the $fromdate , $todate and $studentid ... and it just show me the blank alert.

Comment: the console shows the failed to load http://http://localhost/vidyalaya/index.php?admin/get_attendance_report resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Open that Ajax call... I think some error is there... That's y no alert is coming...

Comment: I think the main cause to sending data from ajax is not working because when i pass the numeric id to the controller query it shows the data with alert otherwise it didn't show up anything in alert. Is there any other way to send data from ajax to controller.

Comment: which browser are you using??

Comment: I am using google chrome ... but its not passing value... if i echo any number and string through controller it shows the alert

Comment: no, it shows the numbers or strings i was echoing through that controller ... but from passing values via ajax .. it didn't show up anything . i also try to append the values directly to controller url but it can pass only one parameter ... 
url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/get_attendance_report/', + studentid, 

so is there any way to pass multiple values from url

Comment: Ok thank you i made a mistake, i forgot to call back the data to controller using $_POST now its working. but the problem is the date between function is not working on sql .. is there any way to get the data between 2 dates on codeigniter.

Comment: The query I have given is not the exact query... U have to change column names n table name...

Comment: I have done it and append it correctly with the table as well with the id.

Thank You Thanks a Lot

Comment: @SumanDahal consider accepting the answer if it was helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

```html
function get_attendance_report(){
        $studentid =$_POST['studentid'];
        $fromdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['fromdate']));
        $todate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['todate']));

        $this->db->where('date >=', $fromdate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $todate);
        $this->db->where('student_id =', $studentid);
        $attendance_reports = $this->db->get('attendance')->result_array();


        foreach ($attendance_reports as $row){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
            echo   '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>';
            echo   '<td>'.$row['remarks'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        
    }
```

This is how i done it ... Thank You so much @Niranjan

Answer (score 0):

```html
function get_attendance_report(){
        $studentid =$_POST['studentid'];
        $fromdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['fromdate']));
        $todate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['todate']));

        $this->db->where('date >=', $fromdate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $todate);
        $this->db->where('student_id =', $studentid);
        $attendance_reports = $this->db->get('attendance')->result_array();


        foreach ($attendance_reports as $row){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
            echo   '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>';
            echo   '<td>'.$row['remarks'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        
    }
```